# How to make custom symbology in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, symbology

So, I have two rasters showing land surface temperature where first is in range 18 - 27, and other 23 - 37. What I want is to make the same symbology for them so that these datasets can be comparable to each other. In this case they can't be compared since in first raster red color is showing values of cca more than 26, while on other raster values of 26-27 are represented by an orange color and so on for all the values. I would like them to be in stretched symbology since I have continuous data.

Can it be done?

[image: /]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by setting the upper and lower limits of the stretch 20 something that encompasses both ranges, in your case something like 20° to 40°.

You do this by setting the stretch properties as highlighted below:

[image: symbology]

The original DEM values are from -80 to 1075. By setting the stretch type in min-max you can change the display range by editing the values, I use as an example 0 to 200.